# How to obtain 256 bins/pixels from an LBP image?

Tags: c, image-processing, pattern-matching, computer-vision, feature-extraction

I am implementing uniform LBP in C. But I am confused regarding the concept. I have implemented LBP. Suppose i have an image of 512*512 dimensions. After LBP it will be 510*510. Now how to get 256 bins/pixels from this LBP image.

```
for(i=1; i < image_src->width - 1; i++)
    {
          for(j=1; j < image_src->height - 1; j++)
          {
              const unsigned char center = image_get_pixel_value(image_src, i, j , 0);
              unsigned char code = 0;
              if(center <= image_get_pixel_value(image_src, i-1, j-1 , 0))
                code += 128;
               if(center <= image_get_pixel_value(image_src, i-1, j , 0))
                code += 64;
              if(center <= image_get_pixel_value(image_src, i-1, j+1 , 0))
                code += 32;
              if(center <= image_get_pixel_value(image_src, i, j+1 , 0))
                code += 16;
              if(center <= image_get_pixel_value(image_src, i+1, j+1 , 0))
                code += 8;
              if(center <= image_get_pixel_value(image_src, i+1, j , 0))
                code += 4;
              if(center <= image_get_pixel_value(image_src, i+1, j-1 , 0))
                code += 2;
              if(center <= image_get_pixel_value(image_src, i, j-1 , 0))
                code += 1;

              image_set_pixel_value(image_tar, i-1, j-1, 0, code);
          }
      }
```

And this is the lookup table:

```
int  UniformPattern59[16][16] = {
             1,   2,   3,   4,   5,   0,   6,   7,   8,   0,   0,   0,   9,   0,  10,  11,
            12,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,  13,   0,   0,   0,  14,   0,  15,  16,
            17,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,
            18,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,  19,   0,   0,   0,  20,   0,  21,  22,
            23,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,
            0,    0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,
            24,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,
            25,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,  26,   0,   0,   0,  27,   0,  28,  29,
            30,  31,   0,  32,   0,   0,   0,  33,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,  34,
            0,    0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,  35,
            0,    0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,
            0,    0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,  36,
            37,  38,   0,  39,   0,   0,   0,  40,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,  41,
            0,    0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,  42,
            43,  44,   0,  45,   0,   0,   0,  46,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,  47,
            48,  49,   0,  50,   0,   0,   0,  51,  52,  53,   0,  54,  55,  56,  57,  58
    };
```

Answer (score 5):

I guess you may misunderstand the concepts about LBP. The LBP has couple of variants: basic LBP, uniform LBP and rotation-invariant uniform LBP.

In the **basic LBP**, we compare the gray-scale value between the centre pixel and one of its neighbour pixels (interpolated pixels for more accurate result) to get the binary coding (0 or 1) for the bit. Usually, we set the radius of this coding scheme as 1 and the number of neighbours as 8 as default configuration. Therefore, we can get the local binary pattern (LBP) for the centre pixel after comparing all the 8 neighbours, which is a 8-bit binary number, e.g., 01011110 or 11110000. Here, we can see that the range of this kind of LBP is from 0 to 255 if we convert the binary number to decimal number. We usually classify each pixel's LBP code into one of the 256 kinds of patterns to form the histogram for further classification or recognition tasks, which are the 256bins/pixels in your question.

However, there is something different in uniform and **rotation-invariant uniform LBPs**. That is, the number of patterns is not 256, where the rotation-invariant uniform LBP only has 10 kinds of patterns. The rotation-uniform LBP has 9 rotation-uniform LBPs and 1 others, in which the 9 rotation-uniform LBPs cover 90% patterns over an image usually.

So, in rotation-invariant uniform LBP, you only need to produce a 10-bins histogram for further processing, e.g., classification or recognition. First, you code each pixels as the rotation-invariant uniform LBP, which may produce an image.rows*image.cols matrix. Then, classifying each pattern (the matrix element) to one of the 10 patterns to form an array to represent the histogram.

*Some papers for your information:*

1. LBP on Scholarpedia, http://www.scholarpedia.org/article/Local_Binary_Patterns
2. C++ code by LBP authors, http://www.cse.oulu.fi/CMV/Downloads/LBPSoftware
3. Multiresolution gray-scale and rotation invariant texture classification with local binary patterns, http://www.rafbis.it/biplab15/images/stories/docenti/Danielriccio/Articoliriferimento/LBP.pdf

Comment: Thanks alot for such a detailed explanation. What i am not understanding is this: " Here, we can see that the range of this kind of LBP is from 0 to 255 if we convert the binary number to decimal number. We usually classify each pixel's LBP code into one of the 256 kinds of patterns to form the histogram for further classification or recognition tasks, which are the 256bins/pixels in your question." Though i read different research papers and even have gone through the links that you shared. If you can explain this point a bit more

Comment: The motivation to convert the 8-bit binary code of a pixel into a decimal number is for human's understanding. Actually, the number of basic LBP coding (pattern) types is 256 even if we do not convert the 8-bit binary to a decimal. You can image that the minimal binary code of a pixel is 00000000 (equivalent to 0 in decimal number), and the maximal binary code is 11111111 (equivalent to 255 in decimal number). So, this is why I said the range of the LBP codes are from 0 to 255 in decimal.

Comment: (con't) But, in programming implementation, you do not need to convert the binary code (may be represented in bit operation in C++) to the decimal number. You can directly count the number of each binary codes and this may leads to a histogram with 256 bins (bins is equivalent to the types of LBP codes (patterns)).

Comment: What I am confused with is: I am implementing uniform LBP with a lookup table. It has 256 values. I know to combine all of the uniform into 58 bins and the rest in 1 bin, so total will be 59. I have implemented LBP, i am adding it above. its giving me 510*510 image. I don't understand how to map it to the 256 values of lookup table. I don't know why i am not getting this thing.

Comment: @ Zhu Lu,please help me out with this thing. I need it for my project.

Comment: I do not understand the UniformPattern59[][]? And you need to use interpolation neighbours, instead of the actual neighbours in the image matrix.

Comment: Can you suggest me some help in implementing Uniform LBP without Lookup table ( Because you said you don't understand the lookup table)

Comment: using bit-movement-operation in C++. sorry for so long time not responding your message because I was busy on my project.:)

Comment: @BlueBee hi...I am stuck at similar problem. Got the basic LBP working...don'tknow how to proceed with histogram and bins...could you please share your code? mail me perhaps.....?